# Удалить www. из url

Tags: php

необходимо удалить из доменного имени `www`

домен может быть с `www` или без него, если он есть требуется удалить его

пытался вот так

```
$search = 'www.';
$st = 'www.site.ru'; 
$res = preg_replace('~' . preg_quote($search) . '~', '', $st, 1);
```

вроде все работает, но если домен будет `sitewww.ru` то на выходе получаем `siteru`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменим только те которые идут в начале строки, или после двух косых или после пробельного символа:

```
<?php
$search = 'www.';
$st = 'http://www.sitewww.ru'; 
$res = preg_replace('/(^|\/\/|\s+)('.preg_quote($search).')/', '${1}', $st, 1);
echo $res;
```

Comment: спасибо. то, что надо